# Filter list of tuples in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to filter a list of tuples in haskell. 
I want to return the tuples where the first and the second element are the same.

I'm trying this one

```
 filter ((==fst).snd) [(1,2), (2,2), (3,3)]
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `uncurry`:

```
filter (uncurry (==)) [(1,2), (2,2), (3,3)]
```

alternatively you can match on each tuple:

```
filter (\(x,y) -> x == y) [(1,2), (2,2), (3,3)]
```

Comment: If I used do to get a Char, could I used the above to fetch y, like this? filter (\(x,y) -> x == 'a') [('a',"is for apple”),('b',"is for boy")] –– returns "is for apple"

Comment: @bentaisan - Yes, it will work on any tuple where the first element has an `Eq` instance. You need a ``\`` before the tuple though: `filter (\(x, y) -> x == 'a'))`.

Comment: I got this...I don't want to return the tuple, I just want the [Char] string:  `filter (\(x, y) -> x == 'a') dictionary -- dictionary = [('a',"apple"),('b',"boy")] `, so I want to get "apple" back, not the tuple. p.s.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
filter (\p -> fst p == snd p) [(1,2), (2,2), (3,3)]
```

---

`(==fst).snd` means `\p -> snd p == fst`, obviously this would not work. If you really do not want to use lambda abstraction, and want a pointless version, here is one way to achieve that (you need to import `Control.Applicative` first):

```
filter ((==) <$> fst <*> snd) [(1,2), (2,2), (3,3)]
```